# count distinct values while left joining

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, left-join, distinct

I have a table that looks like this:

```
people:
+-----+--------+-----+
|  id |   name | age |
+-----+--------+-----+
|  25 | Alpha |  30 |
| 113 |   Beta |  21 |
|  10 |   Test |  19 |
+-----+--------+-----+
```

and another like this:

```
table2:
+-----+-----------+--------------+
|  id |   company | candidate_id | 
+-----+-----------+--------------+-
|   1 |  Google |           10 |    
|  36 | Microsoft |          113 |    
| 137 |  Google |           10 |    
|   2 | ITCompany |           10 |    
+-----+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

I want to join people with table2 such that i can find the total number of DISTINCT companies corresponding with each unique person id. My end result should be something like this:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  id |   name | companies |
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  10 |   Test |         2 |
|  25 | Alpha |         0 |
| 113 |   Beta |         1 |
+-----+--------+-----------+
```

How can I do the count for companies?

```
SELECT people.id, name, company
FROM people
    LEFT JOIN reports on people.id = table2.people_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by people.id and count the distinct companies:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.company) companies 
FROM people p LEFT JOIN reports r
ON p.id = r.people_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

I assume the `id` is the primary key of the table `people`.

Comment: what is c.id ? Yes, id is from people

Comment: @Jbd a typo, it should be r.id.

Comment: for the first row, it gives me 3 instead of 2. it doesn't seem to count distinct companies only

Comment: For example, candidate id 10 occurs thrice but 2 of them are for the same company

Comment: @Jbd do you have different ids for the same company, like the ones in the sample data for Google? You edited the question and changed the sample data and this changes the requiriment.

Comment: @Jbd see my edited query

Comment: Could you please explain what this part does ```COUNT(DISTINCT r.company) companies ```

Comment: @Jbd it counts the distinct values of the column company of the table reports for each id of the table people.