# Need records based on two columns unique in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Mysql table like this I want to show a pie chart to show data of count on the basis of column including column A and B group.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | User1 |
| A1 | User1 |
| B1 | User1 |
| C1 | User2 |
| C1 | User3 |
| D1 | User1 |
| C1 | User1 |
| A1 | User1 |
| C1 | User1 |

I tried the my sql query

```
SELECT  a.`columnA`,a.`columnB`
    FROM `table_one` a
    GROUP BY  a.`columnA , a.`columnB`;
`
```

Desired output

| ColumnB | Count |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 4 |
| User2 | 1 |
| User3 | 1 |

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796703/count-distinct-values-while-left-joining for similar question. you can achieve the result using count(distinct columnName) in query

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like

```
select column_b, 
       count(distinct column_a)
from your_table
group by column_b
```

Comment: Yeah!  Note the distinct in  `count(DISTINCT column_a)`